# Passing the parameter value as NULL in SOAP UI rest service for ESS job

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement in which I have to call the SubmitESSJobRequest through SOAP UI. In the ESS, there are few parameters whose value I need to pass as NULL. Can you please guide how it can be achieved.

Comment: not sure about ESS specifics, but in xml null is represented either as the absence of the element altogether (ie when the schema says min-occurs =0) or using xsi:nil=true attribute.  try <param xsi:nil="true">

Comment: `<param xsi:nil="true">` gives me a validation error. Removing the parameter element altogether always works.